# Scala way / idiom of dealing with immutable List

Tags: list, scala, immutability

I have found successes using ideas of immutable List but I am stumped when come to this piece of code here. I find myself has written something more Java than of Scala style. I would prefer to use `List(...)` instead of `Buffer(...)` but I don't see how I can pass the same modified immutable `List` to the next function. `guesses` is also modified within `eliminate(...)`.

Any suggestions to help me to make this the Scala way of doing this is appreciated. Thanks

```
    val randomGuesses = List(...) // some long list of random integers

    val guesses = randomGuesses.zipWithIndex.toBuffer

for ( s <- loop()) {
    val results = alphaSearch(guesses)
    if (results.size == 1) {
        guesses(resultes.head._2) = results.head._1
        eliminate(guesses, resultes.head._2)
        }
    else {
      val results = betaSearch(guesses)
      if (results.size == 1) {
        guesses(resultes.head._2) = results.head._1
        eliminate(guesses, resultes.head._2)
      } else {
          val results = betaSearch(guesses)      
          if (results.size == 1) {
            guesses(resultes.head._2) = results.head._1
            eliminate(guesses, resultes.head._2)  
          }
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some general tips since this might be better suited for [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) and the code posted is incomplete with no samples.

You can use pattern matching instead of `if` and `else` for checking the size.

```
results.size match{
  case 1 => ... //Code in the if block
  case _ => ... //Code in the else block
}
```

Instead of mutating `guesses` create a new `List`.

```
val newGuesses = ...
```

Then pass `newGuesses` into `eliminate`.

Lastly, it looks like `eliminate` modifies `guesses`. Change this to return a new list. e.g.

```
def eliminate(list: List[Int]) = {
 //Eliminate something from list and return a new `List`
}
```

Comment: Even better for the pattern matching case, try `results match { case x :: Nil => // Code in the if block`.  I think matching on the structure of the list itself is cleaner than checking the size, and it gives you immediate access to the (single) element of the list.

Comment: match doesn't solve my multiple nested if-s and creating a new List from elminate does not work because I will use guesses again in a for-loop. Sorry, I missed out the for-loop and I have modified my code to reflect that

Comment: You can use replace `if-else` statements with `match` and then refactor. Instead of using a `for` loop you can use recursion. Return a new `List` from `eliminate` and the call your function with the new list.